# Problem with loop that does the rotation of words

Tags: c

This code I made rotates a string per word n times. There seems to be a problem in this part

```
for(i=0; i<=rotations; i++)   
{
    strcpy(tempString, string2[row]);
    
    for(j=row; j>=1; j--)
    {
        strcpy(string2[j], string2[j-1]);
    }   
    strcpy(string2[j], tempString);
}
```

So, I tried to change j=row to j=row-1 because I thought that this was the problem, but it does not seem to work. What's wrong in this part guys or does the problem lie on other parts?

I would appreciate your help. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int row;
char finalString[30];
char* stringRotate(char string2[][100], int rotations);

int main(void) {
char string[100];
char string2[100][100];
int numOfRotations;

printf("Input a string: ");
gets(string);
printf("Input number of rotations: ");
scanf("%d", &numOfRotations);

int col = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(string); i++)
{
    if (string[i] == ' ' || string[i] == '\0')
    {
        string2[row][col] = '\0';
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        string2[row][col] = string[i];
        col++;
    }
}

 printf("%s", stringRotate(string2, numOfRotations));

return 0;
}

char* stringRotate(char string2[][100], int rotations){
int i, j;
char tempString[50];    



for(i=0; i<=rotations; i++)
{
    strcpy(tempString, string2[row]);
    
    for(j=row; j>=1; j--)
    {
    strcpy(string2[j], string2[j-1]);
    }   
    strcpy(string2[j], tempString);
}

for(i=0; i<=row; i++)
{
    strcat(finalString, string2[i]);
    strcat(finalString, " ");   
}

return finalString;

}
```

Comment: `row` is never initialized. What do you expect it to be? The title of your question also doesn't seem to match the question itself. Please fix this.

Comment: The title and body of your question seem to be asking two entirely different questions. Can you try to fix this with an [edit]?

Comment: @Brian sorry forgot to edit the title.